# CSRF token from either the request body or request headers did not in Cake PHP

Tags: cakephp, csrf

We do not need CSRF token in our internal cake PHP application, So how we cane disable it from my application, Please help me

Thanks

Comment: Just don't do any of the things described [here](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/security/csrf.html)?